# Exception in thread "main" javax.media.opengl.GLException: No default device available

Tags: java, macos, jogl

I've been trying to install JOGL on os x for the past few days, but keep getting this error when I try and compile a test program.  Anyone know how to get rid of this message?

EDIT: I first attempted to install system-wide by dropping in jars and jnilibs into //System/Library/Java/Extensions/, per various instructions I found online, but received the above error.  I later tried to install JOGL within an eclipse workspace and still received the error.

Answer (score 2):

JOGL 2 works under Mac OS X. Please ensure that no other version is installed on your machine and use the very latest version. Please check that all JARs are present, those for GlueGen runtime and those for JOGL, the JARs containing the Java libraries and the JARs containing the native libraries. Read [the instructions in our wiki](http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE).

If it still fails to work, contact us on [our official forum](http://forum.jogamp.org) and/or fill a bug report.

Edit.: There is often an obsolete version of Java3D installed by default as an extension under Mac, it relies on an obsolete version of JOGL which can cause some troubles. Uninstall those craps and it should work.

Comment: I attempted to install JOGL by dragging various cryptically named jars and jnilibs into my java extensions folder.  I presume I uninstall by deleting these.  How do I differentiate these from the necessary and unrelated files in the same folder?

Comment: NEVER install a Java library as an extension, this is NOT what is suggested in our wiki and it can break your environment by causing conflicts with the versions used by applications and applets. If you see Java3D or JOGL installed as an extension, uninstall it whatever the version. Finally, there is nothing cryptically named, there are naming conventions that you don't know or you don't understand. You just have to use jogl-all.jar, gluegen-rt.jar and the JARs containing their native libraries whose names should contain "-natives-" and "macosx-universal".